# AWS: How to give an IAM user access to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to give access to an **IAM user** to an **EC2 instance**.
In other words, I'd like him to be able to access it using **ssh** with **keys** just like I would with the **root user**:

```
ssh -i ACCESS_KEYS_DIRECTORY_PATH ubuntu@ec2-instance-id.region.compute.amazonaws.com
```

For this I can follow 2 scenarios:

**SCENARIO 1:**

1. Create an EC2 instance using the root user.
2. Attach a policy to this EC2 instance that allows the IAM user to access it

**SCENARIO 2:**

1. Attach a **policy** to the **IAM user** that allows him to create an EC2 instance.
2. Sign-in to the console with the IAM user, and create the EC2 instance.
3. Generate the **ACCESS_KEYS** that gives the user access to this instance.

**SCENARIO 3:**

1. Create an instance using the root user
2. Since each instance has its own `ACCESS_KEYS`, there's no need to do any of what I mentioned above, and I can simply hand the access keys to the IAM user.

So which scenario should I follow and why?

Comment: Access to the actual instance is out of the scope of IAM. Normal linux / ssh access mechanisms are what grants access at that level, IAM is Not involved. E.g. if you provide no ssh keys onto the instance not even the root user can access it. At that point you need to terminate and try again.

Comment: You have to give a `.pem` key to the user and allow the necessary connectivity on the security group. SSH does not require IAM access in any way. Moreover, the AWS access keys the RSA private key (`.pem`) are entirely different things.

Comment: What you need to instead is create a keypair within the EC2 console and reference that keypair when creating the instance. Or if you already have the instance running add the keys to the authorized_keys file

Comment: And never should *you* hand out ssh key pairs, the user needs to create the key themselves and then somebody adds the public key of that keypair to the server. All three scenarios do not work.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional EC2 Keypair based SSH access is completely independent from AWS IAM. Your generated private keyfile can be given to anyone and they would have SSH access to the instance (assuming the user can connect to the SSH port and the SSH daemon is running).

If you need to provide SSH access via IAM policies, [Enabling and controlling permissions for SSH connections through Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-enable-ssh-connections.html) is probably your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your Linux instance using [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html).

> Amazon EC2 Instance Connect provides a simple and secure way to connect to your Linux instances using Secure Shell (SSH). With EC2 Instance Connect, you use AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies and principals to control SSH access to your instances, removing the need to share and manage SSH keys. All connection requests using EC2 Instance Connect are logged to AWS CloudTrail so that you can audit connection requests.

> You can use EC2 Instance Connect to connect to your instances using the Amazon EC2 console (browser-based client), the Amazon EC2 Instance Connect CLI, or the SSH client of your choice.